# Chart axes in PowerPoint file

Tags: c#, charts, powerpoint, gembox-spreadsheet, gembox-presentation

I'm creating a chart (of `ComboChart` type) in the PPTX file using GemBox.Presentation (together with GemBox.Spreadsheet). I'm using the code from the [PowerPoint Chart](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/presentation/examples/powerpoint-charts/412) example and added parts of the [Excel Combo Chart](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/examples/c-sharp-vb-net-create-excel-chart/301#combo-chart) example.

This is what I have so far:

```
var presentation = new PresentationDocument();
var slide = presentation.Slides.AddNew(SlideLayoutType.Custom);
var chart = slide.Content.AddChart(GemBox.Presentation.ChartType.Combo, 25, 25, 300, 500);
var comboChart = (ComboChart)chart.ExcelChart;
var worksheet = comboChart.Worksheet;

worksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "Name";
worksheet.Cells["A2"].Value = "John Doe";
worksheet.Cells["A3"].Value = "Fred Nurk";

worksheet.Cells["B1"].Value = "Salary";
worksheet.Cells["B2"].Value = 4023;
worksheet.Cells["B3"].Value = 3263;

worksheet.Cells["C1"].Value = "Max";
worksheet.Cells["C2"].Value = 4500;
worksheet.Cells["C3"].Value = 4300;

worksheet.Cells["D1"].Value = "Min";
worksheet.Cells["D2"].Value = 3000;
worksheet.Cells["D3"].Value = 2800;

comboChart.CategoryLabelsReference = "A2:A3";

var salaryChart = comboChart.Add(GemBox.Spreadsheet.Charts.ChartType.Column);
salaryChart.Series.Add("=B1", "B2:B3");

var minMaxChart = comboChart.Add(GemBox.Spreadsheet.Charts.ChartType.Line);
minMaxChart.Series.Add("=C1", "C2:C3");
minMaxChart.Series.Add("=D1", "D2:D3");

presentation.Save("output.pptx");
```

And this is what I get:
[image: Combo chart in PPTX file]

Now my problem is that I cannot find any way to access and format the Category axis and Vertical axis.

I tried to use `chart`, `comboChart`, `salaryChart`, and `minMaxChart` objects, but none of them have any axes properties!?

How can I, let's say, set the axes titles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the axes of the Combo chart, you'll need to use the axes of one of its containing charts, so either `salaryChart` or `minMaxChart`.

Now the reason why you don't see any axes properties on them is that they are of a base type (`ExcelChart`). You need to cast them to a derived type, like this:

```
var salaryChart = (ColumnChart)comboChart.Add(GemBox.Spreadsheet.Charts.ChartType.Column);
salaryChart.Series.Add("=B1", "B2:B3");

salaryChart.Axes.Horizontal.Title.Text = "My Categories";
salaryChart.Axes.Vertical.Title.Text = "My Values";
```

Comment: I tried to access axes property from excelChart base type however I get error as my scenario is same to the question trying to make chart using spreadsheet on powerpoint. Error say : `ExcelChart does not contain definition for axes and no accessible extension method axes accepting a first argument of type ExcelChart could be found`. could you please help. Thanks.

Comment: @user273181 the base type doesn't have axes because not all charts have axes. You'll need to cast your chart into one of the derived types, like `ColumnChart` that is used in the above answer.

Comment: okay i understand what u mean. Thanks for quick reply.